# How to insert spaces at the beginning of line in wordpress.com?

Tags: wordpress.com

In wordpress.com blog posts, if you add a few spaces to the beginning of a line, when you publish the post, the application removes those spaces. How can I add spaces before the first word of a line?

Answer (score 5):

Generally, one should not "add spaces at the beginning of a line"; this is something to be left in the age of typewriters. But if this is exactly what you need, then switch to the HTML mode of the editor and put

```
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

(as many times as you want) at the beginning of a line. Be careful not to switch to the Visual mode of the editor after that, which may remove this HTML code.

**That said**, what you probably want to do is to *indent* paragraphs in your post. This can be done with a style: in HTML mode, put the line

```
<div style="text-indent: 1em;">
```

at the beginning, and

```
</div>
```

at the very end of the post. The number 1 can be made smaller or larger, as you prefer: 0.75, 1.4, etc.